# MATLAB: How do I check if any element in my matrix is nan and do something if that is the case

Tags: matlab, if-statement, nan

I know I can use `isnan` to check for individual elements, such as

```
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        if isnan(A(i,j))
            do something
        end
    end
end
```

However, instead what I want to do is

```
 if any(isnan(A))
      do something
 end
```

When I tried to do this, it doesn't go into the argument because it is considered false. If I just type `any(isnan(A))`, I just get `1 0 1`.
So how do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
any(isnan(A(:)))
```

Since `A` was a matrix, `isnan(A)` is also a matrix and `any(isnan(A))` is a vector, whereas the `if` statement really wants a scalar input.  Using the `(:)` notation flattens `A` into a vector, regardless of the initial size.